# GET URL parameter in angular 4 / 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to pass an URL using the GET method.

Actually a microcontroller is sending the GET sequence to a specific web page. On the Web site, I'm trying to get the parameters embedded in the GET sequence for further storage and processing.
When I write directly the destination URL in chrome, it works with two methods :

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params);
    this.device_id = params.ID;
    this.Voltage = params.Voltage;
    console.log(this.device_id);
    console.log(this.Voltage);

    this.device_id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['ID'];
    console.log(this.device_id);
    this.Voltage = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['Voltage'];
    console.log(this.Voltage);

    });
```

The first method with queryParams is when I send this URL : (http://www.quatuoradbd.com/Reception?ID=00-80-56-de-fr-00-d8-af&Voltage=2650)

the second method with snapshot is when I send this URL :
(http://www.quatuoradbd.com/00-80-56-de-fr-00-d8-af/2650)

These two methods work when I pass the URL directly in the bar navigator.

But when those URL's are sent by a microcontroller, it doesn't work.
I know that it should work because when my previous version of web site was written in PHP, everything was doing fine.

On the web server side, I receive parameters (by parameters I mean the resource address appended to the domain name) with :

```
    if(isset($_GET['Nbres']) OR isset($_GET['Local']))
    {
    $Nbres=$_GET['Nbres'];
    $Local=$_GET['Local'];
    }
```

But I don't understand why with Angular 4 (and 5) it doesn't work.

In Angular 4, is there a parameter that has to be modified? Or could this be coming from a specific router parameter that must be set? ... or a parameter on the server?
If anyone as a hint, I would appreciate.

I join you my index.html, my app-routing.module.ts if it can help.

my index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Connectedfuture</title>
       <base href="/">

       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
       <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my app-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '', redirectTo: '/Accueil', pathMatch: 'full' },
       { path: 'ConfirmationCompte/:email', component: 
       ConfirmationCompteComponent },
       { path: 'Graphiques/:id', component: GraphiquesComponent },
       { path: 'Accueil', component: AccueilComponent },
       { path: 'Projets', component: ProjetsComponent },
       { path: 'Clients', component: ClientsComponent },
       { path: 'Histoire', component: HistoireComponent },
       { path: 'Inscription', component: InscriptionComponent },
       { path: 'Identification', component: IdentificationComponent },
       { path: 'Reception/:ID/:Voltage', component: ReceptionComponent },
       { path: 'Reception', component: ReceptionComponent },
       { path: 'Map', component: MapComponent },
       { path: 'App/:ID/:Voltage', component: AppComponent },
       { path: '**', component: InconnuComponent }
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

Comment: your application is served with nginx ? 
maybe you don't redirect your parameters to your angular app.

Comment: No my server uses Apache and I have put a .htaccess for the redirection with this code : 
        `RewriteEngine On
             # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
             RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
             RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
             RewriteRule ^ - [L]
             # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
       RewriteRule ^ /index.html`

Comment: Do you need to route your application, or do you need to call your backend with URL parameters ? Because that was not clear for me ;

Comment: Actually the microcontroller sends the data to the frontend (angular5) using the GET method and the parameters passed along. On the frontend the data is retrieved from the URL frame, then parsed and processed and finally passed on to the backend (API symfony 3.3) where it is finally stored.

Comment: Create github repo with a minimal reproduction of the problem. You are pulling all of your stack into the question and it is not possible to even start helping you. If you make your question short and clear it will be answered

Comment: I attach you the link Github https://github.com/Sauniere/test. If anyone can help me, I would appreciate